# SwiftUI avoid ForEach HStack overgrowth container

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

I'm trying to achieve the design that has progress inside a cell like so:
[image: correct design]

But the problem is that I cannot find an easy way to prevent the `ForEach` overgrowth the screen size when there is more max items eg.: `50` which leads to:

[image: issue]

What I would like to be is:

[image]

I don't want to control/calculate maximum items of the `ForEach` as this is driven by the business logic, the graph could be just clipped.

Desired:

- The cell  won't outgrow the container
- `Text 1` and `Text 2` is spread to the left and right hand side.
- When the graph has less items the text sets minimum width:
  [image]

Currently what I have:

```swift
struct Row: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            Circle()
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: 41, height: 41)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)

            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text("Text")
                        .font(.bodyS)

                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.black)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)

                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 3) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< 20) { _ in
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                        .frame(width: 3, height: 10)
                                }
                            }

                            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                                Text("Text 1")
                                    .fixedSize()
                                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                                Text("Text 2")
                                    .fixedSize()
                            }
                            .font(.bodyS)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 16)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                            .fill(.gray)
                    )
                }
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
                .layoutPriority(1)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
    }
}

struct Row_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                Row()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinking about this sentence
"I don't want to control/calculate maximum items of the ForEach as this is driven by the business logic, the graph could be just clipped."

If you're not going to show those elements in any way (like scrollable content). What's wrong in for example `prefix(50)` on the `viewModel` level? (Trying to understand better the challange you face)

Comment: I can do prefix(50). Not a problem. I just don't care how many items is there. UI should just render properly as many as they might fit on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the frame size and use `.clipped()` (and include a `spacer()` to ensure that it is aligned to the left).

```
import SwiftUI

struct Row: View {

    var numberOfItems: Int = 100  // <- determine the number of items in your data
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            Circle()
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: 41, height: 41)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)

            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text("Text")
                        .font(.body)
                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.black)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)

                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 3) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< getNumberOfItems(), id: \.self) { _ in
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                        .frame(width: 3, height: 10)
                                }
                                Spacer() // <- HERE
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: 200) // <- HERE
                            .clipped() // <- HERE


                            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                                Text("Text 1")
                                    .fixedSize()
                                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                                Text("Text 2")
                                    .fixedSize()
                            }
                            .font(.body)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 16)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                            .fill(.gray)
                    )
                }
            }

            Spacer(minLength: 0)
                .layoutPriority(1)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
    }

    func getSpacing(numItems: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return(10.0)
    }

    func getNumberOfItems() -> Int {
        return(numberOfItems)
    }
}

struct Row_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                Row()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but static 200 as a maximum width is not a solution, as it would require to handle each device maxWidth separately. I already implemented one solution based on the UIScreen bounds - all the padding and frames to calculate the maximum graph width, but I'm looking for something more flexible than manual calculations.

Comment: Have a look at Geometry reader which will be able to calculate the size for you. - the key here is that if you want to have something clipped - then you must set a frame size.

Comment: I tried also GeometryReader, with couple approaches like having ZStack only to get the frame size. But still because the Text 1 and Text 2 want to make the frame bigger and the outer spacer smaller it doesn't give good results. For now I just calculate the max width of the graph by manually calculating screen's width minus all of the other padding and view sizes included in the horizontal axis.